# How to pass parameters to controller using ajax and javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, controller

I am trying to delete an item from shopping cart using Ajax with javascript, but I have trouble passing parameters to the controller. The parameters are null in controller.

My javascript code shows as below:

```
function removeRow(itemId, rowID){
        if (xmlHttp == null)
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }
        var query = "action=remove&item=" + itemId;

        /* alert(query); */
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged()
        {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
                row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "addTo.htm", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.send(query);
        return false; 
        /* var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row); */
```

}

My controller code shows as below:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/addTo.htm")
public class AddToController{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        System.out.println(action);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        ArrayList<Item> cart;
        if(action.equals("remove")){
            System.out.println("cart size is" + cart.size());
            Long itemId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("item"));
            ItemDAO itemDao= new ItemDAO();
            Item item = itemDao.get(itemId);
            cart.remove(item);
            System.out.println(cart.size());
        }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

The action and item are null in the controller.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a GET request, so add the parameters as a query after your URL:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "addTo.htm?" + query, true);
```

and pass in null (rather than your query string) when calling the .send method:

```
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Also, the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header is only used when you're sending serialised parameters but using POST, so remove the `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader` line.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started